# RegEx javascript not matching correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small javascript funtcion :

```
function GetFilteredListLimited(event) {
    var $source = $(event.target);
    var $Pattern = event.data.Pattern;
    var RE = new RegExp($Pattern, 'i');
    if (RE.test($source.val())) {
        console.log('RegEx match');
    }
};
```

The pattern used is:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

Which should match most email-addresses.

Using http://regexpal.com/ I can see that the Pattern is correct. But for some weird reason the script already matches at the 4th character after @

abc@abcd should not give a match, but is does. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: It is not giving any match..? see https://regex101.com/r/jM4xJ3/2

Comment: Looks like the culprit is the constructor notation. Try double-escaping the `.` so that it looks like `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$`.

Comment: That email is valid. `a@com` is a valid email address. According to the specification, Top Domain Names are allowed as the domain name in an email. (Just wait until someone makes the TDN `abcd` and you'll see websites like `example.abcd`) But my bet goes to you having selected 'Invert results' in the options on that website. It works fine on https://regex101.com/r/jF7bU7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of `RegExp` constructor where escaped characters must be double-escaped. So, your regex string passed to the RegExp constructor should look like:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

The fix can be introduced like this:

```
var RE = new RegExp($Pattern.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'), 'i');
```

It will work if the escape symbols are used consistently.

Comment: Double escaping the . did it.